# How to get full date from month and year from first two columns and update the third column with the full date

Tags: mysql

I have a table with three columns:

- The first column `month` is of type `TINYINT` and contains the month (e.g. 8 for August, 12 for December).
- The second column `year` is of type `SMALLINT` and contains the year (e.g. 2018).
- The third column `date` is of type `DATETIME` and is empty and by default `NULL`.

**example data:**

```
+----+-------+------+----------------------+
| id | month | year |        date          |
+----+-------+------+----------------------+
| 1  |   7   | 2018 |        NULL          |
+----+-------+------+----------------------+
| 2  |   7   | 2018 | 2018-07-01 00:00:00  |
+----+-------+------+----------------------+
```

**What I want to do is to take the month and year, fuse it to  create a full date and update the date column with the full date where date is NULL.**

Meaning, to go from row 1 to row 2 with the help of SQL. The day of the full date does not matter to me, thus by it can be `01` by default or even `20`.

I'm pretty much at a beginner / experienced beginner level when it comes to SQL as I use it only as a very basic user writing simple querys so please stay patient with me.

Comment: Where did you get the `01` from to format `2018-07-01 00:00:00` ? i assume from the id column ?   This is pretty much a wrong approach as i assume the id column to have a `AUTO_INCREMENT` which can grow larger then the month days?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention this. I will update the question. The **01** is not the ID but the day of the date. The day is irrelevant to me though so it can be **01** by default or even **20**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following, using [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) with [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) (or [`CONCAT_WS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)):

```
-- solution using STR_TO_DATE with CONCAT
UPDATE table_name 
  SET `date` = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`year`, '-', `month`, '-1'), '%Y-%c-%e')
WHERE `date` IS NULL

-- solution using STR_TO_DATE with CONCAT_WS
UPDATE table_name 
  SET `date` = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', `year`, `month`, 1), '%Y-%c-%e')
WHERE `date` IS NULL
```

You can also [create a `VIEW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html) to get the last column (`date`) dynamically without updating your table:

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
  SELECT `id`, `month`, `year`, STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', `year`, `month`, 1), '%Y-%c-%e') AS `date`
  FROM table_name
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb2a493b380ba2c48b8e914a7bbe7e74)